# What is a restricted Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a class C multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by the French embassy. My meeting in Paris has been reduced to two days. On the warning side it says this visa does not allow allow entrance to the Schengen area. What should I do to visit Italy for the remaining five days before I go back home?

Comment: Since France is in the Schengen area, a French C visa which does not allow Schengen entry sounds weird. Is it a Schengen visa with territorial validity restricted to *France*?

Answer (score 4):

It seems a no-brainer that if the visa says it does not allow you to travel to other Schengen countries, and supposing your nationality does not allow free entry for tourism purposes on Italy, that you have got to obtain a separate Italian tourist visa.

Your best bet is to visit the Italian embassy. However, to be on the safe side, first double-check with French authorities whether your current visa does allow you to re-entry in France.